# Making an object continously spin and then stop after hitting a wall

Tags: animation, graph-editor

I want to make a shuriken spin while also following a path towards a destructible vase, it will then smash through and then hit the wall and stop spinning, it then looks like it has been stuck into the wall. Ive tried rotating it but it just ends up offsetting the path[image]

Anybody know how to do this?
Thanks a million-Icarus.

Comment: Just animate it's local rotation or rotation delta. add one keyframe at exactly the time it hits the wall and then make rotation graph fall to zero

Comment: Can you please add a picture or link, I'm more of a visual learner so it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Posted as an answer bellow. Never post private email adresses like that in public. You may get a lot of unwanted spam

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create your Shuriken mesh and curve object to follow.

Add a *Path Constraint*, a *Follow Path* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> > Follow Path) parent or whatever suits your need.

After the shuriken is correctly following your path, select it as active object, place the timeline in Frame 0 and keyframe it's *Delta Rotation* by pressing the <kbd>i</kbd> key, then move the timeline to the last frame of your animation and do the same, keyframing the last *Delta Rotation* again.

This will do nothing on its own, you now have to adjust it in the *Graph Editor*.

Either open a new *Graph Editor* area, or switch to one of the default screen layouts for Animation which will automatically set up the editors for you.

Now in the graph editor, with the select the shuriken as active object, select the animation curve handle for rotation in the last frame and move it up or down, depending on the direction you want it to rotate, the amount of degrees you want it to spin (amount of turns * 360 degrees), you will probably have to eyeball it to see what looks best, but probably a very high number.

To make the speed constant turn all animation handles into *Vector* type.

[image: Shiriken keyframe]